# HCatalog Hive: show database error

Tags: hadoop, hive, vertica

I am trying to connect to Hive tables from Vertica according to the documentation.

https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/HadoopIntegrationGuide/HCatalogConnector/HCatalogConnectorRequirements.htm?Highlight=curl

Curl command:

```
$ curl http://hcathost:50111/templeton/v1/ddl/database?user.name=hive; echo
```

But I am getting this error. I can't understand what's going wrong! I am new to this, so any help is highly appreciated.

The error message:

```
{"statement":"show databases like '*';","error":"unable to show databases for: *","exec":{"stdout":"","stderr":"which: no /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.4.0-1.cdh4.4.0.p0.39/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop in ((null))\ndirname: missing operand\nTry `dirname --help' for more information.\n/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.4.0-1.cdh4.4.0.p0.39/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 26: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.4.0-1.cdh4.4.0.p0.39/lib/hcatalog/sbin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: No such file or directory\n/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.4.0-1.cdh4.4.0.p0.39/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 136: cygpath: command not found\n/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.4.0-1.cdh4.4.0.p0.39/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 139: exec: : not found\n","exitcode":127}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like `WebHCat` is somehow not configured right.  Maybe check over `webhcat-default.xml` and `webhcat-site.xml`?

Comment: I have not changed the webhcat-default.xml and webhcat-site.xml does not exist. Can you point out what scepter gets executed for that curl command?

Comment: *I meant wat script gets executed.

Comment: Why is it starting from home produser? `line 26: /home/produser/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh:` where can I change that path?